# Getting undefined method erorr rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to create a list of 'Active User' and 'Unactive User'.

And i have User model and Voucher model(has quantity:integer).

In my routes.rb

```
      resources :users do
        resources :vouchers
      end

  get 'active' => 'home#active', as: :active
  get 'unactive' => 'home#unactive', as: :unactive
```

In my home_controller.rb

```
  def active
    @users = User.all
    @vouchers = Voucher.all
  end

  def unactive
    @users = User.all
    @vouchers = Voucher.all
  end
```

In active.html.erb

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <% if user.vouchers.quantity >= 1 %>
        <%= user.name %> <br>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In unactive.html.erb

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <% if user.vouchers.quantity == 0 %>
        <%= user.name %> <br>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But i got this error : "**undefined method `quantity' for**"

How can i get this quantity? 
I want to show user that have `voucher.quantity == 0` on my unactive list.

Thank!

Answer (score 1):

`user.vouchers` is a list of Vaucher objects, calling `quantity` on it makes no sense, it's a property of each object, what would you expect it to return?

If you wan't to count how many vouchers does a user have then use the `count` method instead as `user.vouches.count`.

Or you may want to get the quantity of the first voucher with `user.vouchers.first.quantity`.

Or maybe you want to check if all vouchers have quantity 0? `user.vouchers.all?{|voucher| voucher.quantity == 0}`

It's not clear what are you trying to do with that if condition.

Comment: user.vouchers.all?{|voucher| voucher.quantity == 0} works on unactive. But i tried user.vouchers.all?{|voucher| voucher.quantity >= 1 } on active, but it didnt work

Comment: Nasty N+1 problem. Why not use `joins`?

Comment: @jvillian how to use joins sir?

Comment: Sorry, on mobile device. Check the ActiveRecord Query Guide.

Comment: @Garbela, can you explain what you need? I gave a few ideas but I guess there are better solutions if you can explain your logic better. Maybe you can use a counter to keep tracking of active/unactive users, your original question has code but no context.

Comment: @arieljuod I want to show user.vouchers.quantity == 0 on my unactive list but i got undefined method `quantity' for

Comment: @Garbela, I understand that, that's why I'm asking you to explain the logic of what you WANT, the business logic behind what you have tried. What does an "active" user mean? ALL vouchers with quantity >= 0? AT LEAST ONE voucher with quantity >= 0? You are doing "User.all" and itearing over all of the to filter, I guess you can do better than that but you are not giving clear examples of: your data, which users would be considered active, which unactive, etc. You need to explain all the context. How does a user go from active to unactive? your question is missing a lot of info.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Thanks :)

```
  def active
    @users = User.joins(:vouchers).where('vouchers.quantity > 1').distinct
  end
```